# JMeter: errorlevel = -1073741819 when running test via CMD

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, errorlevel

I am trying to run some performance tests via CMD. It is a pretty simple environment. We launch a Jenkins build with testing parameter and the Jenkins slave calls PSExec with jmeter command on a remote VM.

Whenever I try to run the tests (either with complete flow from Jenkins or directly from CMD) I get the following error:

```
errorlevel=-1073741819
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As far as I've read on the internet, this error is specific for Access violation.

This is the command I use for starting the test:

```
jmeter_path\bin>jmeter -n -t jmeter_path\bin\tests\Test.jmx -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jparam1=%param1% -l \\remote_ip\Results_Build_115\Results.csv -j \\remote_ip\Results_Build_115\jmeter.log -e -o \\remote_ip\Results_Build_115\HTMLReport
```

Later Edit:

Here is the error from Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 8.0.1610.12, time stamp: 0x5a39c48e
Faulting module name: java.exe, version: 8.0.1610.12, time stamp: 0x5a39c48e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000b54b
Faulting process id: 0x2f98
Faulting application start time: 0x01d470feb367816d
Faulting application path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
Report Id: a01a4071-1ab6-4b52-8a54-e50ba51da6bf
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Observations:

- Running tests from GUID work as expected
- Result folder is on a remote VM with full read/write access. The result folder is generated before running tests.
- I get the same error even if I run tests directly from CMD
- I have a total of 19 params in the call (didn't include them in the above example)
- OS: Windows 10

Comment: Something is wrong with sending more than 9 params. If I send the request with less or equal to 9 numbers of params, everything is working as expected. Any idea on how can I make this work?

Comment: Hi @bogdanov Have you found why this happens ? can't we send more than 10 jMeter parameters through commandline... any solution or workaround here ?

Comment: @MusaffirLp yes. I could not send the parameters directly to Jmeter and for this I've used a batch file to shift the parameters. See second answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694861/how-to-pass-more-than-9-parameters-to-batch-file/21695048

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I fixed removing some spaces betwen commands.

Comment: Add some details, examples, descriptions. Then your answer can be more helpful.

Comment: Please elaborate to make the answer more useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

How about reduce -J numbers, I did that for my case, it works.
Couldn't handle too many -J to pass para

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass your properties through "-J", put them in a file and reference it through the "-q" option. https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options