# How can I pass more than 10 arguments in windows batch file or linux shell script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I need to pass more than 10 arguments to a single batch file (shell script)
but after the 9th argument it will not work (it will take from beginning)

code sample

```
 echo Hello! This a sample batch file.
    echo %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 %11 %12 %13 %14 %15 %16
    pause



>mybatchdotbat a b c d e f g h i j  k l m n o p
```

can anyone give solution for this

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `%10` is being read as `%1` `0`. In a Unix shell, you could use `${10}` to refer to the tenth argument, or `shift` to remove the first argument and decrement all subsequent arguments by 1 (useful in a loop).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, `%10` is getting interpreted as `%1` `0`.

To fix this, in either a batch file or a shell script, you can save the first argument in a variable, then use `shift` to decrement all remaining arguments by 1. When you call `shift`, `%1` (`$1` in a shell script) is now gone, the old `%2` becomes `%1`, the old `%3` becomes `%2`, etc. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8328669/4318200) for more details.

In a shell script, you can also refer to the tenth argument using `${10}`.

Answer (score 2):

you can get all parameters with `%*` and parse them with a `for` loop:

```
for %%i in (%*) do echo %%i
```

Note: your parameters may not contain certain characters ("Standard delimiters"), for example `,` or `;` unless you quote them:

```
mybatch.bat first second "this is the third" "four, not five" five 6 7 8 9 ...
```