# Is it possible to bypass the 9-argument limit in `commandArgs()` for R programs in a bash script?

Tags: r, bash, commandargument

i'm currently running a r program where i use already 9 argument with "commandArgs()" for my bash script, but it seems i can't use a 10th argument, the program doesn't take it, is there a way i could do it and won't have to make an other program just for that ? thanks in advance for your help ! After some question here is the script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(DT)Args 
library(data.table)

args <- commandArgs()

table1 <- read.csv(args[6])
table2 <- read.csv(args[7])

idem <-as.character(intersect(table1$x, table2$x))
same <- data.frame( nom_colonne = idem)

pasidem <-as.character(setdiff(table1$x, table2$x))
passame <- data.frame( nom_colonne = pasidem)

pasidem2 <-as.character(setdiff(table2$x, table1$x))
notsame <- data.frame( nom_colonne = pasidem2)

write.csv(same, args[8], row.names = F,  quote=F)
write.csv(passame, args[9], row.names = F,  quote=F)
write.csv(passame, args[10], row.names = F,  quote=F)
```

As you can see i ask args 6 to 10 (since 1 to 5 already taken by the system) but it seems i can't use a 10th argument

Comment: Use `"${10}"` or `"$@"` ? but the question is to vague though

Comment: sorry new here and don't really know how to put it better, my script already use 9 argument so it work, but when i had a 10th argument i have an error (on my terminal) meaning it can't detect the 10th one (i tried the same command with 9th argument and it work) so the question is more how can i use a 10th argument on my script ? it seems commandArgs only let me use 9 argument max.

Comment: Show some code, and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Welcome to SO, guillaume! I've heard of 9 being a (soft) limit for windows cli utils, but there are ways around it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38390433/3358272). I don't know of any limit imposed by `commandArgs`. It would be very helpful if you make your question more _reproducible_, namely a minimal script attempt, how you are calling it (including the shell type, i.e., `cmd` or `bash`), and all errors/warnings. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thank you!

Comment: thanks you ll do it and try make a little model to show what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [littler](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler) and its `r` front-end.  It provides a vector `argv` (just like C does) which is also easier to use programmatically than `commandArgs()`.  (We most often use this with additional command-line parsing packages; I liked [docopt](https://cran.r-project.org/package=docopt) a lot and have [many examples](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/tree/master/inst/examples).)

##### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/r

for (i in seq_along(argv)) {
    cat("Argument", i, "is", argv[i], "\n")
}
```

##### Demo

```
$ ./argcount.r a b c d e f g h i j k l
Argument 1 is a 
Argument 2 is b 
Argument 3 is c 
Argument 4 is d 
Argument 5 is e 
Argument 6 is f 
Argument 7 is g 
Argument 8 is h 
Argument 9 is i 
Argument 10 is j 
Argument 11 is k 
Argument 12 is l 
$
```

(This worked all the way up to 26 when I just tested with all letters.)

Littler ships with a `Makevars` for Linux and macOS and could build on Windows but I have not a need. If someone wants to "port" this, the very similar package [RInside](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RInside) is structured similarly and can provide a model.

Answer (score 0):

BASH has a builtin named `shift` which might help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo ${1} ${9}
shift 9
echo ${1}
```

If you save the above script as shift_example.bash and make it executable then you can call it as below to see what I mean.

```
./shift_example.bash A B C D E F G H I J K L
```

The second `echo` should print `J` which is the tenth argument.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html for details.

Comment: The quesstion was about an R program, not a shell script.

Comment: Point taken @DirkEddelbuettel. The question is not very clear (to me at least). It does mention _my bash script_ and I answered just in case it helps guillaume.